# Align text to center in div with another div as percentage background

Tags: html, css, alignment

Situation: I have a div which is 100% width of its parent. There is text in this div which needs to be centered/

Also within that div I have another element which is supposed to have a percentage of the outer divs width, be it 0 to 100% (this area will have a background-color set).

The code may look something like:

```
<div style="text-align:center; width:100%;">40%
    <div style="background-color: green; width:40%;"></div>
</div>
```

So I would want the text '40%' to be centered and to the left of that 40% of the outer div will have the green background color.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: error in the second div append the style format check the question first before asking .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="text-align:center; width:100%;position: relative;">40%
    <div style="background-color: green; width:40%;position: absolute;top: 0px;left: 0px; height: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

You need to set `position: relative` on the outer `div` to ensure that the inner `div` is positioned relative to it
You need to set `position: absolute` on the inner `div`, and set it's `top` and `left` to 0, and it's `width` and `height` to 100%

Also, you left out the `style="` in the second `div`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="text-align:center; width:100%;">40%
    <div style="background-color: green; width:40%; margin:0 auto;">40%</div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7sLB/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="text-align:center; width:100%;">40%
<div style="background-color: green; width:40%;"></div>
</div>
```